# Table sort on header click in the pagination using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdo, pagination

when i clicked on books link it order the books in ascending and if i clicked again on the link it will order the books in descending ,,,, my problem is when i clicked on the books link he order the two books that Apparent to me ,,, i want him to order the books even if book be in next page.

this function to get books an display it in table

```
   public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2)
{
   $sql_start = $start * $limit;
   $sql_limit = $limit;

   $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
   $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
   $statment->execute([
       ':username' => $this->username
   ]);
   $result = $statment->fetchAll();

  echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'>

  <tr>
   <th><a onclick='sortTable(1)' href='#'>Books</a></th>
   <th>Action</th>
   </tr>";
   foreach($result as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
   echo "";

 }
```

and this JavaScript function to Ascending descending the row

```js
<script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;     
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're performing the pagination on the php side rather than the javascript side. That means you should similarly do column ordering on the php side - clicking on a header should cause a new call to "getBooks" with a different "ORDER BY" clause.

So the sortTable() function should be an ajax call to the server, where "getBooks" is performed again with the ORDER BY dictated by which header was clicked (and if the order is ascending or descending). If the user clicks on the "Books" header then the query looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit ORDER BY nameOfBook " //add DESC if necessary
```

**EDIT:**

A quick explanation:

When paginating tables you can do it either client side (in this case javascript) or server side (in this case php).

Doing things client side would mean you get all of the data from the server (so all the books in the library), as a JSON object probably (could be XML or something else) and then you generate the table from that data in Javascript, limiting the number of books per page, but allowing you to access the other books because you have all the data to hand. This would mean not using "LIMIT" in the SQL query, because you're sending everything. This has the advantage of limiting calls to the server (if that's an issue) but could mean a lot of number crunching on the client side if you have a lot of data.

Alternatively, you have the pagination done on the php side. In this case the query will include the LIMIT to keep data small, but you probably also want to send the client the full number of entries so that the number of pages can be calculated (this could be done using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS). From javascript you send an AJAX request to the server for the data. Here are some resources:

AJAX:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/index.htm

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

JSON format:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

The ajax request goes to a php page which does the sql query and returns the data. The data could be an object (JSON most likely) or directly the HTML of the table. The former is best for big projects, but the second might be quicker. Once the server has sent back the data you'll display it (either by generating the table in Javascript from the JSON object, or by simply inserting the HTML if that's what you went for).

Sorry if this is perhaps a bigger job than you had originally planned for.

Comment: so should i use ajax to do this process?

Comment: Yes I'm afraid so. So you shouldn't have the php file echo the table, but rather have a div that will contain the table, send out an ajax request to the php file, which then returns the table html and then javascript populates the div with the html that the php has generated. Hope that makes sense

Comment: please sir can you give me more details ,, i am fresh self learner and i must finish this task today @Michael Beeson

Comment: Done a big ol' edit with links to tutorials that might help.